# Why isn't psycopg2.connect checking the password?

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I'm playing with `psycopg2` for the first time today, and I'm trying to understand how passwords work... I have a test script which drops a table, recreates the table, adds a row, and prints the row. My question is why does the `connect` command work whether or not I give it a correct password? e.g. this line:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="mydb",host="localhost",port=5432,user="amos",
                        password="asdf")
```

and this line:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="mydb",host="localhost",port=5432,user="amos",
                        password="asdf123")
```

unexpectedly do the same thing, and the rest of the script completes with no error. Clearly only one of those lines should work regardless of what the password actually is. As expected, I do get an error if I try a `user="amos123"`, since that user doesn't exist. If it matters, my PostgreSQL was installed with `Postgres.app`.

Answer (score 6):

After some research, I discovered that login criteria are specified in a file called `pg_hba.conf`, which in my installation by default has this line:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

which according to [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-TRUST) the `trust` value means it doesn't check passwords. I guess that was unintuitive to this newb because if that behavior was what I wanted, I wouldn't have set passwords in the first place. I'm posting it here to save future googlers some time.

Comment: Pg still lets you set a password because you might want `peer` or `trust` auth for a user from a particular host, but want to require a password from a different host. And the client is allowed to give a password when not required so that it doesn't have to behave differently based on `pg_hba.conf` settings it doesn't know or control.